# Unable to make swing undo/redo system work for a simple paint program.

Tags: java, swing, undo

I followed steps from many articles but the undo system not behaving as expected. first,  the undo button goes back correctly till the first edit but can't go beyond the first edit. also, when I click undo and then re-edit it circles back to the last edit. It's better if you execute the code and see yourself.

Another question, while I'm trying to figure out a solution I read that saving images in an Array is memory intensive, is that true even for this simple paint class, and what is the alternative? saving the image's graphic?

```
import java.awt.*;import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;import java.awt.event.*;import java.util.ArrayList;import javax.swing.*;import javax.swing.event.*;import javax.swing.undo.*;
public class Painter extends JFrame{    
//attributes//
Painter.Canvas canvas;
JPanel controlPanel;
JButton undoButton;
JButton redoButton;
PainterHandler handler;
Container container;
//undo system elements//
UndoManager undoManager;         // history list
UndoableEditSupport undoSupport; // event support

//constructor//
public Painter()
{
    super("Painter-test");
    controlPanel = new JPanel();
    undoButton = new JButton("undo");
    redoButton = new JButton("redo");
    handler = new Painter.PainterHandler();
    container = getContentPane();
    canvas = new Painter.Canvas();

    this.organizer();
}// end constructor

public void organizer()
{
    controlPanel.setLayout(null);
    controlPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(120,350));
    controlPanel.setBackground(null);

    //add undo listeners to undo/redo buttons.
    undoButton.addActionListener( new AbstractAction()
                {
                    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent evt ) 
                    { undoManager.undo(); refreshCanvas(); refreshUndoRedo();}
                });
    redoButton.addActionListener(new AbstractAction() 
                {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt ) 
                    { undoManager.redo(); refreshCanvas(); refreshUndoRedo(); }
                });

    // initilize the undo/redo system.
    undoManager= new UndoManager();//history list
    // event support, instance.
    undoSupport = new UndoableEditSupport();
     //add undoable edit listener to the support instance.
    undoSupport.addUndoableEditListener(new UndoableEditListener() 
                {
                    public void undoableEditHappened (UndoableEditEvent event) 
                    { 
                        UndoableEdit edit = event.getEdit();
                        undoManager.addEdit( edit ); 
                        refreshUndoRedo();
                    }
                });
    refreshUndoRedo();

    canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,400));
    //place buttons on panel.
    undoButton.setBounds(10, 160, 80, 20);
    redoButton.setBounds(10, 181, 80, 20);

    //add components to panel.
    controlPanel.add(undoButton);
    controlPanel.add(redoButton);

    //add panels to window.
    container.add(canvas,BorderLayout.WEST);
    container.add(controlPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
}//end organizerTab3()

public void refreshCanvas() { canvas.repaint(); }

//refresh undo, redo buttons.
public void refreshUndoRedo() 
{
    // refresh undo
    undoButton.setEnabled( undoManager.canUndo() );
    // refresh redo
    redoButton.setEnabled( undoManager.canRedo() );
}


//INNER CLASSES
ArrayList<BufferedImage> imagesArray = new ArrayList<BufferedImage>();
BufferedImage imageCopy;
Graphics graphics;
BufferedImage  image;
int index;
private class Canvas extends JPanel 
{
    public Canvas() 
    {
        //Panel properties
        setSize(600,400);
        setBackground(new Color(84,84,118));

        image = new BufferedImage(getWidth(), getHeight(),BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        //add Listeners.
        addMouseMotionListener(handler);
        addMouseListener(handler);
    }//end constructor

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    }
}//end inner class PaintPanel


private class PainterHandler extends MouseAdapter
{
    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event)
    {
        if(event.getComponent().equals(canvas))
        {
            if (image != null)
            {
            // Paint into the image
            graphics = image.getGraphics();
            graphics.setColor(new Color(249,30,138));
            graphics.fillOval(event.getX(), event.getY(), 20, 20);
            imageCopy = new BufferedImage(canvas.getWidth(),canvas.getHeight(),BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            imageCopy.getGraphics().drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
            canvas.repaint();
            }
        }
    }//end mouseDragged(MouseEvent event)

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event)
    {
        if(event.getComponent().equals(canvas))
        {
            //UNDO SYSTEM START//
            //add image to the array.
            imagesArray.add(imageCopy);
            // get image's index.
            index = imagesArray.indexOf(imageCopy);
            //create AddEdit instance of type UndoableEdit. 
            UndoableEdit edit = new Painter.AddEdit(imagesArray, imageCopy,index);
            // notify the listeners
            undoSupport.postEdit( edit );
            //UNDO SYSTEM END//
        }
    }
}//end MouseHandler class

private class AddEdit extends AbstractUndoableEdit
{
    private ArrayList<BufferedImage> undoableImagesArray;
    private BufferedImage undoableImage;
    int undoableIndex;
    public AddEdit(ArrayList<BufferedImage> v, BufferedImage img, int i) 
    {
        undoableImagesArray = v;
        undoableImage = img;
        undoableIndex = i;
    }
    public void undo() throws CannotUndoException 
    {
      undoableImagesArray.remove(undoableImage);
      if(!undoableImagesArray.isEmpty()) 
          image = (BufferedImage)undoableImagesArray.get(undoableImagesArray.size()-1);
      canvas.repaint();
    }

    public void redo() throws CannotRedoException 
    {
        undoableImagesArray.add(undoableImage);
        image = (BufferedImage)undoableImagesArray.get(undoableImagesArray.size()-1); 
        canvas.repaint();
    }

    public boolean canUndo() { return true; }
    public boolean canRedo() { return true; }
}//end class AddEdit

public static void main(String[] s)
{
    Painter p = new Painter();
    p.setSize(800, 500);
    p.setVisible(true);
    p.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
} 
}//END CLASS Painter
```

Comment: *"while I'm trying to figure out a solution I read that saving images in an Array is memory intensive"*  It depends on the resolution, bit depth and number.  But the typical JRE can hold hundreds of (for example) 640x480 images with full color and transparency.

Answer (score 2):

You don't use undoableIndex. In fact you should not remove the image from array but instead move the pointer.

canUndo() should return true if the list is not empty and the pointer >0

canRedo() should return true if the pointer!= size() of the list

Comment: Thank you, do you mean I should use undoableIndex as a pointer? I modified undo and canUndo but I still get the same result:
`public void undo() throws CannotUndoException 
    {
        image = (BufferedImage)undoableImagesArray.get(undoableIndex-1);
        canvas.repaint();
    }
 public boolean canUndo() { if(!undoableImagesArray.isEmpty() && undoableIndex>0) return true; return false;}`